# Should I use "arrived" or "reached"

Tags: grammar, differences, british-english, language-formation

Sometimes when I come back from my brother's house he asks me to let him know when I am at home. Now, in that situation which one of the following is correct :

```
I've reached home now.
```

OR

```
I've arrived home now.
```

Comment: In the UK at least, the most usual ways to say this (over the phone) are 'I've just got home' or 'I'm back!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 'reach' is strictly divalent: you can't say "I've just reached." You must add a noun group or a locative:

> "I've just reached the station."
>
> "I've just reached home."
>
> "We've only just reached here."

'Arrive' is intransitive

> "We've just arrived (/ at the station)."

The fact that it also can be followed by a locative confuses the issue:

> "I've just arrived home / here."

Comment: It means I can say that "I've just reached home" :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it depends on the actor. If you are going towards a place then you can say that you are 'arriving'. On the other hand, for someone who is sitting at that place, you are reaching that place.

For example, `I am reaching the railway station` sounds OK for me to say; but for people who are already at the railway station `one more passenger is arriving`.

So I would prefer `reach` over `arrive`.

PS: I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I think your approach here is clear and logical, and the final result is cultural. Just to add, in the US, *I've arrived*, less formally, *I'm here*. As we approach, we tend to say, *We're almost there* but We're *arriving*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "I've arrived home" sounds more natural.

The difference is subtle. "Reached" can suggest a stage in a long or difficult journey, while "arrived" may give more of a sense of a journey's end. "I've arrived home" sounds like the end of the story. "I've reached home" suggests than you may keep going, or that getting there was a difficult accomplishment.

The origins of the words give a hint of the flavour. To reach means to stretch out, while arrive means to come to the shore (ending a journey by ship).